# Im doing a project for my dads company to do with anemometers on vessels. I need help directions and degrees

Tags: python-3.x

In a circle there is 360 degrees. if the vessel is facing east, the computer shows that it is facing 90 degrees. the anemometer tells the office that the wind is coming form 90 degrees also. so the reading shown is 90 degrees. But its intact 180 degrees because it is coming from the south not east. I have this part completed but if the vessel was facing 300 degrees, and the wind is coming 90 degrees to the vessel, the reading comes out as 90 from the anemometer, but it should infect be 210. I've created a program that takes in the boat direction and wind direction and if both inputs are from 0 to 180 then I can add them both together to receive the true wind direction. but if the inputs are from 270 to 360 then the total will go past 360 degrees and come out as lets say 540.

How could I make my program restart counting the degrees when it gets to 360 degrees?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], otherwise there's no way we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. As was mentioned previously, you need to use modulus 360 to keep your angles within 0-360. You should also use modulus 360 on the result in case your ship angle is small enough to result in a negative value after subtracting the wind angle relative to the vessel.

```
def calculate_wind_angle(vessel_degrees, wind_degrees_from_vessel):
    return ((vessel_degrees % 360) - (wind_degrees_from_vessel % 360)) % 360

vessel_degrees = 300
wind_degrees_from_vessel = 90

wind_degrees = calculate_wind_angle(vessel_degrees, wind_degrees_from_vessel)

print(wind_degrees)
```

Answer (score 2):

The conventional way to restrict a calculation between 0 and some number N is to get the *modulo* of a number. We might also call this the "remainder" of a number when divided by something else. The result of the modulo will always be between 0 (inclusive) and the number you're dividing by (exclusive).

In python, the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) is the percent character - %.

So 1 % 10 is the remainder of 1 divided by 10, or 1. 12 % 10 = 2.  0 % 10 = 0;

Applying this to your case, if you want to limit the values of your calculations to between 0 and 360, you can do all your calculations, and then get the modulo against 360.

An example might look like
`deg = (vessel + anemometer) % 360`